# ignore named sub directories vim telescope

Tags: neovim, telescope.nvim

This question concerns [telescope in vim](https://awesomeopensource.com/project/nvim-telescope/telescope.nvim). I can see any info as to the type of regex being used.

With the following setting I can achieve to ignore **node_modules** only if I start the explorer at the root level where node_modules exist.

telescope.nvim.vim

```
lua << EOF
require('telescope').setup{
   ...
   file_ignore_patterns = {"node_modules"},
   ...
}
EOF
```

How can I achieve the outcome where node_modules is ignored recursively - so ignore any deeply nested node_modules. "node_modules/*" is not working.
Unless I can make telescope respect .gitignore would also be a solution.

Thank you in advance for helping.

Answer (score 4):

From the documentation [here](https://github.com/nvim-telescope/telescope.nvim#options-affecting-sorting), it looks like you can use `%` as a wildcard as well as `*`. I was able to exclude image files in this way:

```
file_ignore_patterns = {'%.jpeg'}
```

I've also been able to get this working:

```
file_ignore_patterns = {'node_modules/.*'}
```

If you're still having problems, the `git_files` builtin supports `.gitignore` out of the box, so use `:Telescope git_files` instead of `:Telescope find_files` if you're in a git repo.

Finally, you can set the `find_command` option in the Telescope setup, so if you're using something like `ripgrep` you could tell it to ignore node_modules from there.

Answer (score 1):

I know this seems late, but the probs in your config is, `file_ignore_patterns` should be defined in `defaults` objects, like this

```sh
require'telescope'.setup({
    defaults = {
        file_ignore_patterns = { "^./.git/", "^node_modules/", "^vendor/" },
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep installed.
This is the grep replacement telescope uses to search and if its installed it will ignore the node_modules.

Most likely telescope uses grep as a fallback.

In my case it was literally just installing ripgrep with brew and like magic the node_modules disappeared :)